# PhD supervisor choice: well-known old professor working on traditional project or young prof working on hot direction?

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision, physics

The thing I'm most concerned about is that whether PhDs who working on traditional project will find a good way out after graduation compared to those working on hot direction.

Also, for the traditional project, I'm familiar with most basic techniques used since I used them in my undergrad, so I can directly start to do the project. While for the hot direction project, I need to spend some time learning new techniques from scratch.

Both supervisors are nice, are willing to guide PhD students in detail and care about students.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on too many unstated and unknown variables - your risk tolerance and ambition, the personalities of the advisors, ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will add more specific description to eliminate more variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a personal choice and depends on your tolerance for risk. My standard advice to students in similar situations follows.

Working with an established researcher in an established subfield is probably going to result in success. And after graduation, people will know how to respond to you and what you do. Collaborators might be easier to find.

The other is risky, and you should understand all of the dimensions of risk. First, working in a "hot" area leaves you open to getting scooped by parallel research elsewhere. If you do get scooped local rules will determine whether you can actually use that research to get a degree or if you have to keep going, potentially getting scooped again. I know of a case in which two students working independently solved an important problem simultaneously. It took a year and an investigation to determine that both could finish and that there was no misconduct. I think both have done well since.

The second risk, assuming that the other potential advisor is untenured is that they may suddenly discover that their own progress is more important than yours and that they have to focus on their own publications, leaving you to founder. There are some other questions here that mention that sort of risk. Depending on how self directed you are this might not matter, but for some people it matters a lot. Some, a few, I think, actually prefer a hands-off advisor. But many require more support. It isn't an impossible situation, necessarily, but it is a risk.

And today's "hot" topic may be quite cool (in the bad sense) in a few years. There is no guarantee about the job market you will face in 3-7 years. Right now it is very tough.

You might also want to consider whether there is a difference in funding between the two areas, both short and long term.

Taking risky research ventures is much easier if you can do so from a secure position. Many people change their research focus several times over a long career. Your dissertation doesn't lock you in to a narrow slot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming funding is not an issue with either lab, you may want to ask each lab’s alumni or current members for objective information. I received my PhD in Molecular Biophysics ten years ago from a research university in Texas. As an applicant we got chances to meet several lab’s students. One guy literally told me do not join that lab because the boss is irresponsible when it comes to mentoring or driving students forward.

For me, it was important to make sure students defend and  graduate in a timely manner. That shows the lab Principal Investigator (PI) is serious and committed to helping you grow. I have seen students doing their PhD thesis in Nobel laureate’s research lab or Howard Hughes lab but PI really don’t care if you are stalled in your progress.

Also consider transferable skills that you will have when you graduate and look for a job. Will your education paint yourself to a corner, or does it give you more leverage to succeed?

Remember, getting out with a PhD is just a beginning. Your next gig will surely require more learning and explorations. I did not answer your question about if you should pursue “hot” topic, but as I see it, I think what I said here should be important for your consideration too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in condensed matter, so some of my experience may not apply to you. But in some fields, it is common to work on two projects at the same time. A safe project to guarantee timely graduation. Then a hot, high risk project to have some fun, or find interesting career, etc.

I am working on two projects. The high risk, hot project will not be completed in time, but I learn a fair bit from the experience. I really glad my advisor insist I also work on the safe project, so I can still graduate with publications.

So if you are interesting in the hot topic, ask if you can have a backup safe project.

Comment: Thanks, that's a quite useful advise, I will ask my advisor whether I can also work on two projects later.